# sending mail with attachment trouble

Tags: php, email

I have a problem with my sending of mails with an attachment. I have this function:

```
function mail_att($to, $subject, $message, $anhang) { 
    $absender = "Sender"; 
    $absender_mail = "noreply@example.org"; 
    $reply = "noreply@example.org"; 

    $path = $anhang;
$uploadname = "Anhang.pdf";

$trenner = md5( time() );
    // Mail Header 
    $mailheader = "Reply-To: " .$absender. "<" .$absender_mail. ">\r\n";
    $mailheader .= "Return-Path: ".$absender_mail."\r\n";
    $mailheader .= "Message-ID: <".$absender_mail.">\r\n";
    $mailheader .= "X-Mailer: PHP v" .phpversion(). "\r\n";
    $mailheader .= "From: ".$absender."<".$absender_mail.">\r\n";
    $mailheader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $mailheader .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n";
    $mailheader .= " boundary = " .$trenner;
    $mailheader .= "\r\n\r\n";
 
    // Mailbody 
    $mailbody  = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format\r\n";
    $mailbody .= "--" .$trenner. "\r\n";
    $mailbody .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $mailbody .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n";
    $mailbody .= $message. "\r\n\r\n";
 
    // Attachment 
    $mailbody .= "--" .$trenner. "\r\n";
    $mailbody .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"" .$uploadname. "\"\r\n";
    $mailbody .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $mailbody .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" .$uploadname. "\"\r\n\r\n";
    $mailbody .= chunk_split( base64_encode( file_get_contents( $path ) ) );
    $mailbody .= "\n";
 
    // Send
    mail( $to, htmlspecialchars( $subject ), $mailbody, $mailheader );
}
```

But when I want to send a mail, I get nothing. Where's the problem? I'm sure that I enter the right receiver EMail! And there is no problem with the mail-server because normal emails work fine.

---

#### Solved

Oh I never thought to use phpmailer. This makes all simpler and it works. All my work for nothing.

Comment: Simple answer: Don't build your own mime emails, especialy with attachments. Use PHPMailer or Swiftmailer, both of which will reduce that whole chunk of code down to about 4 or 5 lines. As well, you're simply assuming `mail()` is working. Did you check its return value? It returns false on failure. Did you check your outgoing server's mail log? Maybe the email's been dumped as spam.

Comment: Are you sending to a gmail account? Google is notorious for filtering emails with attachments sent from what they perceive as "automated" sources.

Comment: **You get nothing?** I see you're trying to send to >> `$to` <<, but that variable **has not been defined**. It's out in cyberspace somewhere. **Add this** `$to = "your_email@example.com";` **below** `$reply = "noreply@example.org";`.

Comment: @Fred I think $to is a parameter of the function so it would be passed along with all the other params.

Comment: @Sébastien Ok, I think I know what you mean now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your'e using PHP's built-in `mail()` function to send the message.

So, PHP will attempt to send the message through a local MTA running on the same server that PHP is running on, as specified by the `sendmail_path` in your `php.ini` file.  Your first place to look would be in the logs of this  local MTA.
These should tell you

1. Whether or not the local MTA received the message from your PHP script and if so,
2. What happened when the local MTA attempted to deliver the message to the remote MTA.